# seperate id for custom post types in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I currently have 5 custom post types on my website for 5 different kind of products.. I would like to give each product an unique ID, seperate from the wordpress-generated ID value.

Illustrated with an example. Lets say I have:
1. Apples
2. Pears
3. Bananas
4. Oranges
5. Melons

If I add my first apple it's ID would be 001. If I then add an orange it's id would be 002, and so on.. If I add a page or a default post, this should have no effect on the product ID.

Is there any way this could be done with some clean and lightweight code? Any help is highly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should always start your id's with a LETTER.

So having a1, a2, a45, etc would work..

Could you please be more specific though. Like how may products will this website have? Under 50? Over 500?

Are the products going to appear on multiple pages?? Are you using a plugin for the products or custom coding?

Comment: Maybe starting the ID with a letter is more valid, my client requisted a certaint, simple type of ID number for each product..

Most likely there will be 400 products in 5 different (post)types..
I use the default archive.php and single.php templates. The ID must be able to be querried in the front end (single.php shows the refnr) and the backend (custom post columns).
I use custom code for the custom post type.

I should have some sort of counter system that counts +1 each time a post is posted in one of the 5 custom post types.. Altough it sounds simple, I haven't yet figured it out..

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the usage - yes but solution exists. You can do this using `custom fields` since wordpress gives the option of custom fields you can use that and write your own function based upon that.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I allready use custom fields for some specifications, but the custom ID should be added automatically.. So I should write some kind of function that first checks all the products and then assigns a unique ID to the new post..?